# Java 8 create map a list of a complex type to list of one of its fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list from some complex type and I want to figure a neat way to construct a list only from one of its fields using Java 8's streams. Let's take as an example:

```
public static class Test {
    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    private String name;
    // other fields
}
```

And imagine that I have a `List<Test> l;`. Now I want to create a new list that contains the values of `name` of all elements in `l`. One possible solution that I found is the following:

```
List<String> names = l.stream().map(u ->u.getName()).
    collect(Collectors.<String> toList());
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this - map a list of a given type to another list of different type.

Comment: You can replace the lambda with `Test::getName`, but otherwise, isn't that neat enough for you?

Comment: @SebastianRedl that is one possible improvement that I did not know about. I was hoping to invoke a single method if such exists. I am still getting used to java 8 so I wanted to explore the options. "There is no better solution" would work for me

Comment: Your approach is fine, even without using method reference. It's readable and efficient.

Comment: Also note that common practice is `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*` and write `.collect(toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using method references is shorter :

```
List<String> names = l.stream().map(Test::getName).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can't avoid at least two `Stream` methods, since you must first convert each `Test` instance to a `String` instance (using `map()`) and then you must run some terminal operation on the `Stream` in order to process the `Stream` pipeline (in your case you chose to collect the `Stream` of `String`s into a `List`).

Comment: This seems like an improvement and it could be the answer I am looking for assuming there is no better option. I mean I would expect from the answer to state something of the sort of "and you can not avoid calling at least two methods on the stream so you can't improve further"

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Well, you can't avoid at least two methods, since you must convert each Test instance to a String instance (using `map()`) and then you must run some terminal operation on the Stream in order to process the Stream pipeline (in your case you chose to collect the output Strings into a List).

Comment: thank you. The information you've added to the answer is in fact quite useful for me - I was not aware of the division of operations into terminal and non-terminal.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it's possible to avoid two *stream* operations if you use a custom collector like `collect(mapping(Test::getName, toList()))`, though it doesn't make the code shorter.